# Getting python geoservice ExportToJPEG to return image as job result?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have an asynchronous geoprocessing service written in python that takes a layer from a mapservice and generates a jpeg image out of it.

To achieve this I am using ExportToJPEG

I need said geoprocessing service to return the image as a job result. How can I achieve that?

```
import arcpy
q ={
"mapOptions": {
"extent": {
            "xmin" : -79.50,
            "ymin" : -4.60,
            "xmax" : -66.50,
            "ymax" : 12.8,
            "spatialReference" : {
                "wkid" : 4686
            }
        }
},
"operationalLayers": [{ "url":"....."}]      
}
result = arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument(q);
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(result.mapDocument, path_to_image)
del result
```

Comment: make sure to set the output directory of your image to `arcpy.env.scratchFolder`, which is the job folder of the geoprocessing service task. [See this existing question and answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183188/arcgis-geoprocessing-service-output-location) for further guidance.

Comment: @GeoSharp The problem is that ExportToJPEG does not return any kind of object, it only creates the JPEG file. I found that one can create a Raster object, but still struggling with that...